# Why does Grothendieck's period conjecture imply Hodge's conjecture?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I would like to know why the Grothendieck period conjecture implies the Hodge conjecture?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you see this written somewhere? I can't find a very good statement of Grothendieck's period conjecture, but what I did find is only stated for abelian varieties. Thus I'd be surprised if it implies the Hodge conjecture. Maybe there is a generalized form of the period conjecture or maybe you mean the Hodge conjecture for abelian varieties?

Comment: I've seen it here this morning : http://www.les-mathematiques.net/phorum/read.php?3,544861  . It's written in french.  :)

Comment: Can you explain to me why the Grothendieck period conjecture implies the Hodge conjecture only for abelian varieties, but not for non-singular complex algebraic varieties for example ? I don't understand the difference. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't know enough about either to answer the question, but that link seems to say that the period conjecture is about any smooth, proper variety over $\mathbb{Q}$. I was just noting that it would probably be a major theorem (so probably not answerable here) if some conjecture that was about abelian varieties implied the Hodge conjecture for all varieties.

Comment: Sorry, but, as i know, a complex algebraic variety over $ \mathbb{Q} $ is a smooth, and a proper variety over $ \mathbb{Q} $, no ?! take a look here : http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vari%C3%A9t%C3%A9_alg%C3%A9brique_projective  Thanks a lot for answearing.  :)